# Any browser doesn't support custom tabs feature?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I tried opera browser ,opera mini, UC mini, duckduckgo all support custom tabs,
just wanna know in 2022 is there any browser still doesn't support custom tabs?

Answer (score 4):

Testing some browsers from the play store now I found the following support custom tabs:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Firefox Focus
- Microsoft Edge
- Samsung Internet
- Brave
- Vivaldi
- Tor
- Ecosia

The following do not support custom tabs

- Opera
- Opera Touch
- DuckDuckGo
- Mint Browser

Not sure why you are seeing different results for opera and DuckDuckGo.

Update: Different browsers have different levels of support for the various custom tabs methods. Google has a good list for the most popular browsers: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/browser-support